# Referencing Xamarin.Android assemblies from .NET Standard Library

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard

Is there some way to add a reference to Xamarin.Android to a .NET Standard class library?

I want to create a Xamarin.Android class library, but not using PCLs, but .NET Standard. Is it even possible? How?

Comment: Learn the project types first, and then you don't even need to ask the question, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Answer: No, you can't. 
(well actually i tested it - and you can reference it as in add a reference to the project / .dll, but you can't actually reference any code)

It works the other way around.
Create a Xamarin Android class library and in there reference a .NET Standard library with code you can share with other projects for different platforms.

.NET Standard provides a mutually 'agreed' API surface of a platform (that implements it). Xamarin Android (actually the Mono Framework) implements .NET Standard.

Xamarin Android has APIs that are not in the .NET Standard. So logically you cannot reference Xamarin Android in a .NET Standard library (because it might make you call APIs that are not available in .NET Standard).